# Expiry System Php

Tags: php, mysqli, count

We're having problem in our system. I dont know how and where to start to put the code in the system. The process is after the seller register his/her account it will start to count 30 days, and after 30 days there will be a pop out notification in the seller account telling that is already expired. I've also try to search tutorial over the internet but it just confuses me. Hoping to help and get rid of it. Thank you :) Btw, mysqli please.

This is the code of the seller checking if the user is valid:

```
   <?php
session_start();

?>
<?php
include("db_connection.php");

$s_username = $_POST['s_username'];
$s_password= sha1($_POST['s_password']);

//check user if exist
$check_query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM seller WHERE s_username = '$s_username' AND s_password = '$s_password'");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($check_query);

if($count == 1)
{
    session_start();
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($check_query))
    {
        $_SESSION['seller_id'] = $result['seller_id'];
        $_SESSION['s_fname'] = $result['s_fname'];
        $_SESSION['s_username'] = $result['s_username'];
        $_SESSION['s_user_type'] = $result['s_user_type'];
        $_SESSION['s_status'] = $result['s_status'];
    }

    header('location: Seller/seller_home.php');
}else if($count>1){
    echo "Error logging in...<br>Please contact administrator";
}else{
    header('location: index.php');
}
?>
```

** Where should i begin to put the code expiration? *

Comment: is the a column in the `customer` table that stores the datetime when the account is created?

Comment: @RamRaider sir sorry i inputted a wrong code it should be seller not customer but i've already edited the code and regarding to your question there is already a column name "date_joined" in the database but not yet in the code

Comment: Please read up on SQL Injection (https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection). Your website can be hacked in seconds.

Comment: Too few information. But in a nutshell, add a `created_at` field at the seller's table with as default value the current timestamp. Then just retrieve it and test for 30 days. Also `sha1` is too weak to store passwords, please have a look at [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this perhaps would be as follows.

```
$maxdays=30;
$now=new DateTime( 'now' );


/*
    other code...
*/


while( $result = mysqli_fetch_array( $check_query ) ) {
    $id=$result['seller_id'];
    $forename=$result['s_fname'];
    $username=$result['s_username'];
    $type=$result['s_user_type'];
    $status=$result['s_status'];
    $joindate=$result['date_joined'];
}

$joindate=new DateTime( $joindate );
if( $now->diff( $joindate )->days > $maxdays ){
    /* bad foo - account exired ~ process account expiry somehow */

    $difference = abs( $now->diff( $joindate )->days - $maxdays );

} else {

    $_SESSION['seller_id'] = $id;
    $_SESSION['s_fname'] = $forename;
    $_SESSION['s_username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['s_user_type'] = $type;
    $_SESSION['s_status'] = $status;

    header('Location: seller/seller_home.php');
}
```

Comment: That is not intended to be ALL of the code- you should pick from it to use within your code - the important piece would be the date comparison portion. Read the code and see what is happening and apply to your question - you may need to tweak it. Incidentally you have used `session_start()` twice - use it once at the very beginning of the script.